# Python and Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, web-frameworks, cherrypy

I currently am working in CherryPy and have a connection to a mssql database using the pymssql library.  I'm looking to create a fancy front end to display the table with fancy sort, edit, and update record features.  Is it possible to do this using Twitter's Bootstrap?  Or should I be looking into a template engine?

I'm new to Python but from what I understand is this flow

- Use a database library to establish connection
- Integrate that python code into a web framework (CherryPy, web2Py, etc...)
- Use a template engine to display the sql queries???

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way for me to display tabular data in a web app is to use datatables : http://www.datatables.net/

There is a post on their blog on how to integrate it with bootstrap look&feel : http://datatables.net/blog/Twitter_Bootstrap_2